# About Cauchy Kovalevskaia Theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm reading an article that says we can garantee a solution u=u(x,t) with $(x,t)$ in a neighboor of origin of $(0,0) \in \mathbb R^{m+n}$ for the problem
$$
L_j u = 0, j=1, \ldots n,
$$
where 
$$L_j = \frac{\partial}{\partial t_j} + \sum_{k=1}^m A_k(t,x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$$
are 2-2 commutative analytic vector fields with the condition
$$u(x,0) = F(x),$$
$F$ also analytic in neighboor of origin of $\mathbb R^m$. I'm trying to use the Cauchy Kovalevskaia Theorem but the things are not filling.

I was trying to solve, for each $j=1,\ldots n$, the problem 
$$
L_j u = 0, j=1, \ldots n, \ \ \ u(x,t_1,\ldots,0,\ldots,t_n) = F(x),
$$
or different inicial data, and try to create our desire solution with sums, product or convolution of that solutions, but I failed.